# How to deserialize this json-data?

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON-data. I using Newtonsoft.Json for deserialize

```
{
    {
        "id":"951357",
        "name":"Test Name",
        "hometown":
        {
            "id":"12345",
            "name":"city"
        },

        "bff": [
            {
                "people": {
                    "id":"123789",
                    "name":"People Name"
                },              

                "id":"147369"
            }
        ],

    }
}
```

I create classes:

```
 public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name;

    [JsonProperty("hometown")]
    public string[] Hometown;

    [JsonProperty("bff")]
    public Bff[] Bff;
}

public class Bff
{
    [JsonProperty("people")]
    public People[] People;

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;
}

public class People
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Namel
}

public class Hometown
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id;

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name;
}
```

But if I call 
`Data datatest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(data);`
where "data" it's json array i have this error:

> The best overloaded method match for 
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)'  has some
>   invalid arguments

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Data needs to be a string - are you passing an object?

Comment: @zerkms it link on json-data.

Comment: "it link on json-data" --- not sure it makes any sense. What type is it?

Comment: it needs to be the raw json response as a string. It cant be a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
"hometown":
{
    "id":"12345",
    "name":"city"
},
```

you are passing a single object while your mapping class is expecting an array:

```
[JsonProperty("hometown")]
public string[] Hometown;
```

Do:

```
"hometown":
[{
    "id":"12345",
    "name":"city"
}],
```

---

In addition:

1. Same problem of not passing it as an array `[]` for `People`
2. Having your `Hometown` property of type `string[]` instead of `Hometowm[]`
3. You have a `{}` set to much around your json

---

This is the valid JSON:

```
{
    "id":"951357",
    "name":"Test Name",
    "hometown": [{
        "id":"12345",
        "name":"city"
        }],

    "bff": [{
        "people": [{
            "id":"123789",
            "name":"People Name"
        }],
        "id":"147369"
    }],
}
```

And Valid code:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name;
    [JsonProperty("hometown")]
    public Hometown[] Hometown;
    [JsonProperty("bff")]
    public Bff[] Bff;
}

public class Bff
{
    [JsonProperty("people")]
    public People[] People;
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;
}

public class People
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name;
}

public class Hometown
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id;
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: The asked question is about a type problem, actually.

Comment: @zerkms - that is also a type problem but there are also 3 others. Fixed